# Finding equation of the tangent line

Tags: calculus

$f(x) = \sqrt{11-x}$ at $x = 2$

Not sure where to start. The square root really confuses me.

Comment: So how about taking the derivative? Have you covered that in class?

Answer (score 1):

First find $y'=\frac{-1}{2\sqrt{11-x}}$
Second find the slope of the tangent at $x=2$ as $m=y'|_2=\frac{-1}{2\sqrt{11-2}}=\frac{-1}{6}$
Finally find the point which is $x=2$ and $y=\sqrt{11-2}=3$ i.e. $(2,3).$

Comment: I don't see how you got $y'=\frac{-1}{2\sqrt{11-x}}$

Comment: $y=(11-x)^{\frac{1}{2}}\implies y'=\frac{1}{2}(11-x)^{-\frac{1}{2}}$ @user3268003